# Explorer context menu command: Take source filename and add it to new text file

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer, context-menu

I'm looking to add a menu item to Windows Explorer context menu for a certain file extension - for the purpose of this example let's say for MP3 files.
Upon rightclicking the file and selecting the menu item I want a command to be executed:
- Take filename and extension (but without the file path) of the file and add that to a new text file which is named the same.

Here's where I'm at with the registry file:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.mp3\shell\Create Text File\command]

@="cmd.exe /C echo #filenameWithoutPath.mp3# >> #filename.txt#"
```

The ## indicates where I am blank. What I can't figure out is to build the command to take the filename of the selected file and add that with extension to a new text file of the same name.

I am almost there with this:

```
"cmd.exe /C echo %1 >> %1.txt"
```

However with this, the filename including path is entered to the file, and the output file name gets double extension (.mp3.txt).

Comment: [Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:

```
"cmd.exe /C For %%A in (%1) do (echo %%~nxA >> %%~nA.txt)"
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thank you for closing the loop and answering your own question. To help other folks understand your solution, could you [edit] your answer and add an explanation? Cheers!